# howto properly add statistics to google analytics from a android app to see correct session duration

Tags: android, google-analytics

i would like to see the duration my users are in my app. I mean exitapp-startapp should be a measure in google analytics ?

When starting my app I call :

```
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder()
            .setNewSession()
            .build());
```

But how to indicate, that my app is stopped or exited ?

Answer (score 1):

After some research on that topic I have come with the conclusion that an app does not explicitly report a session end. Rather the session duration is measured based on the time between the consecutive hits which have been reported since the beginning of a new session and either a session timeout or going to the background.